# With display:flex how to make image fit other div height?

Tags: html, css

Consider the following HTML, the container has the `display:flex` attribute. The container contains an image and a text input:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="flag">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg/800px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png">
  </div>
  <div class="input">
    <input type="text">  
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the associated CSS:

```
* { 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.container  {
    display: flex;
    padding : 10px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    width: 100vw;
}

.flag>img { 
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}


.input>input {
    font-size: 50px;    
}
```

I would like the image's height to fit automatically the input's height. I already tryed a lot of stuffs with `height: 100%;`, `object-fit: contain;`, `object-fit: cover;` ... but nothing is working.

Here is a JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/pcg0qzbx/9/

Answer (score 2):

Since your are using `font-size` you can rely the `em` unit

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  font-size: 50px; /* you only need to adjust this */
  line-height: 1.2;
  height: 1.2em; /* same as line-height */
  /* we can use height: 1lh in the near future */
}
.container img {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.input > input {
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flag">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg/800px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png" height="100">
  </div>
  <div class="input">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a smart solution. It will do the job for my app, therefore, do you think there is a more generic solution?

Comment: @Fifi what do you mean by "generic"?

Comment: I mean dynamics, the height of the image adapts to the other element even if its height changes

Comment: why does switching the value to 1 `line-height: 1;
  height: 1em;` end up not having the same height for the flag and the input. it works for 1.2 but not 1

Comment: @jackblank the div will have the same height (you can inspect the code) but line-height:1 is too small for the text so the input will overflow because the input will try to contain the text unless you add height:100% to it